# gem install ruby-odbc -v '0.99995' Not able install on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I am not getting error while installing gem ruby-odbc -v'0.99995'. 
Please help me to solve this error. I try lot of things but it didn't worked.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-odbc:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/sheetal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for version.h... yes
checking for sql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/sheetal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby
    --with-odbc-dir
    --without-odbc-dir
    --with-odbc-include
    --without-odbc-include=${odbc-dir}/include
    --with-odbc-lib
    --without-odbc-lib=${odbc-dir}/lib
ERROR: sql.h not found
```

I am using ruby 1.8.7 & rails2

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried installing the unix odbc development files?

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.03

Answer (score 10):

If you're on OS X and having this issue try

```
    brew install unixodbc
```

Then you should be able to

```
    gem install ruby-odbc
```